# If Residential Real Estate Isn't Falling, Why Are ETF Funds Falling?

Tags: united-states, real-estate, etf

In most cities, residential real estate prices are not down more than 20% (varies).  Also, some people are being paid a thousand or more in relief, so they may not need to sell, but can stay in their home.  Yet one (of many) popular residential real estate ETFs, REZ, was down almost 50% at one point (52 week high of 82 with 52 week low of 44).  I feel that these ETFs don't represent the underlying asset because shouldn't the underlying asset see a similar contraction?  If residential real estate didn't fall this much, what caused the ETF to?

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer right now. But ETFs investing in property usually use leverage (such as loans) to own a larger assert pool. It's possible the losses were massively magnified by this leverage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some possible reasons:

1. REZ is not just residential real estate:

> The iShares Residential Real Estate ETF seeks to track the investment results of an index composed of U.S. **residential, healthcare and self-storage real estate equities.**

2. The fund does not track residential real estate *prices*. It tracks the *revenue* (meaning rents) generated from real estate. So while property *values* may be up, rent collections have likely been down due to COVID-19 forgiveness and hardships.
3. REITs typically have large distributions, so make sure you are looking at *total* return, not just *price* return.